# How to extract items from a body of text based on a pattern?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a clever way of extracting several items from a body of text, without writing a big loop that grabs each part. I'm not against a loop if it's the best way, but I was wondering if something like regex or something else could help me out here. Lets say I have a body of text like the following ...

```
FOO (1.5) This is a description relating to FOO.
BAR (2) Here's another description (not about FOO this time).
BAZ (100)
```

I'm needing to extract 3 items from it ...

1. The title part prior to the parens.
2. The number within the parens.
3. The description that comes after the parens, if provided.

Can regex be used to reliably extract these bits of information, or is it more flexible to just write a loop that extract them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 3 matching groups here:

```
^(\S+)\s+\(([^)]+)\)\s*(.*)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF0cZ5/1)

Comment: If you were to add a 4th line of text to that example, I think the current regex considers it to be part of the previous line's description group. So maybe I can apply this regex pattern to each single line, instead of the whole body.

Comment: As long as you are using `m` (MULTILINE) modifier you can use it either way.

Comment: It does have multi-line enabled. Check out this regex demo to see what I mean: https://regex101.com/r/fF0cZ5/2